# Android: detect whether wifi access point still in range

Tags: android

I have a method to detect available wifi access ppoints. My method works well but when I am not in the range I still getiing the SSID of the last scan results displayed in my xml file though I am out of the range of this SSID.

```js
 private void check_wifi_available() {
  WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

  if (!wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Please turn your Wi-Fi on",
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }
  
  
  

  WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
  final List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
  if (results != null) {
   // list of access points from the last scan
   List<ScanResult> updatedResults = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();
   // pick Wi-Fi access points which begins with these "SV-"
   // characters.
   for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
    String ssid = results.get(i).SSID;
    // Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^KD-(4[0-9]{2}|500)$");
    // Matcher m = p.matcher(ssid);
    // if(m.matches()){}else{}
    if (ssid.startsWith("KD")) {

     updatedResults.add(results.get(i));
    }
   }
   if (updatedResults.size() > 0) {
    String a = deliverBestAccessPoint(updatedResults);
    textWifi.setText(a.toString());
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best handled by the operating system. The best you could do is set up a timer to periodically scan for WiFi devices and update the results.

Other than that, on rooted devices you may be able to manually send 802.11 requests to the access point/router and do a timeout check for replies.

To clarify: the operating system, when it is scanning for devices, sends out a broadcast message and reports what devices it hears back from. When devices are toward the edge of the 'range' they may report as being available even if connecting and maintaining a connection is problematic because the signal is not strong enough.

EDIT:

For what it's worth, ScanResult has a "level" member variable that reports the signal strength. You could do some more fine filtering for low-strength results. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html

Comment: I am calling this method"check_wifi_available" from the onLocationchange thereby the scan results are always  being updated after 7 seconds. I have already put it on BroadcastReceiver but it took 30 seconds to display the first result, therefore, I put it in the onLocationChange() methode because I have to display the longitude and the Latitude too. This stuf with signal strength is being handled in the "deliverBestAccessPoint" method.